# Line chart Change background color of shaded region on hover (Chartjs)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I've a line chart(chartJs) and i want to change the background colour of shaded region when hovered. I tried below :

```
const data = {
  labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [12, 1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      **backgroundColor: "blue",**
      borderWidth: 5,
      **hoverBackgroundColor: "red",** --> this instead changes the color of point on hover.
    }
  ]
};
```

Other config(Extended Line chart) :

```
options: {
        tooltips: {
          enabled: false,
          intersect: false,
          mode: 'index',
        },
        events: ['mousemove', 'mouseout', 'touchstart', 'touchmove'],
        hover: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: false,
        },
```

I want to change the color of shaded blue region to red.

[image]

Comment: Hey would you able to put this in codepen so we could have better look at it and try it out  to help you

Comment: @AbhijeetAbnave Here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-demo-zau6lb?file=App.jsx

Comment: I should be using fill here on dataset but it should change back to blue immediately i stop hovering a point.

Comment: I read some articles and Github issues, after spending several hours to get a lead on this, This is not practically possible in Chart.js for now, but I have answered this question with a little different approach, I hope it might help you, please accept and upvote the answer so others would get lead on this issue quickly

Answer (score 0):

Here is the stackblitz **[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-demo-iqzdxm?file=App.jsx)**, made the change in your code and it is live

Chart.js does not yet provide any property or method to a change of color of the area under a line graph on hover (to be specific).

But you can achieve this by some other method by re-rendering your canvas on hover, this can be smooth if you have your own custom made hooks, (This is a hackish way of achieving what you want, IT WORKS !!! but I personally will not recommend this)

Here is the explanation

1. I have added one state which will toggle to true & false on Hover

   `const [ isHover, hoverToggle ] = useState(false)`
2. I have shifted const data inside of App function
3. To choose background-color to add this condition

   ```
   backgroundColor: isHover ? "red" : "blue"
   ```
4. Then in onHover event I have added two conditions

a)

```
if ( event.type === "mousemove" && !isHover ) {
    hoverToggle(true);
}
```

b)

```
if ( event.type === "mouseout" ||
     event.type === "mouseleave" ||
     event.type === "mouseup"
   ) {
        hoverToggle(false);
     }
```

5. And most important part pass **isHover** in **useEffect**'s array so it will be revoked on **isHover** toggle

I personally recommend **[d3.js](https://d3js.org/)** for such type of requirements it is a little complex but you can get whatever you want in the graph.

Comment: Toggling based on state will cause re rendering of chart.

Comment: Right now, Chart.js is not providing anything for changing the color of the shaded region on hover